# looping through dataframe columns for multiple plots in the same window

Tags: python, plot

I would like to plot multiple, seperate plots coming from different columns of a dataframe. The columns that should be selected are in a list or array. Giving an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5), columns=list('ABCDE')) 

list_cols     
>['A', 'C', 'D']

or:
array_cols
> 0     A
  1     C
  2     D
```

Now as I said, I would like to make seperate plots for all array/list elements of the dataframe. So i would like to plot A, C and D of the Dataframe df. Does anyone know how this is possible without doing it manually? Maybe something in the sense of:

```
for i in list_cols:
    df[list_cols[].plot()
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `df[list_of_cols].plot()`?

Comment: I would like to have seperate plots (not subplots if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **subplots = True**

```
df[['A','B','C']].plot(subplots=True)
```

[image]

or separate plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for col in ['A','B','C']:
    df[col].plot()
    plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your second version is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I am glad to help:) could you accept the answer?